# WPF exclude summary row from datagrid default sort

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid, columnsorting

I have a datagrid in WPF. The last row in the datagrid is a summary row.

I would like to sort this datagrid without including the summary row in the sorting process.

Is there a way to it without overriding the datagrid's default sorting mechanism by writing a function which removes the summary row, performs the sort and then adds the summary row back to the datagrid?